# Excel: filter consistent information from constantly changing cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am setting up an Excel spreadsheet and I am needing to extract a dollar amount out of specific cells. The problem is that there will always be a dollar amount in the cell but the information on either side of the dollar amount keeps changing.

**Example:**
[image]
As you can see, the content of *Column A* keep changing depending on the date and total amount, but I only need to display the dollar amount. All the text before and after the numbers I want to hide or delete. (Column A can not be modified because it pulls that information from a data source and any changes will get written over).

I've tried a couple of different ways, but I still can't figure out how to combine them together:

- I tried `=RIGHT` to just get the dollar amount but the amount length keeps changing
- I tried `=LENGTH` to get the total length then minus the `Domestic Total as of` off of it, but that only gets me half way there
- I tried `=FIND` to find the `$`, but I couldn't figure out how to remove the extra after that

Also, I forgot to screen shot this: If there is nothing in the cell [*A6*] then I need [*D6*] it to display `$0` because there is no total yet.

Hopefully I explained my problem well enough. If not, I'll try and clear any confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work, using your current methods -

```
=MID(A1,FIND("$",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND("$",A1))-FIND("$",A1))
```

Basically, find the position of the `$` and the position of the first  after the `$` and pull out the string between them.

Throw in an `if()` for the blank -

```
=IF(A1="","$0",MID(A1,FIND("$",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND("$",A1))-FIND("$",A1)))
```

To handle errors you can use this -

```
=IFERROR(IF(A1="","$0",MID(A1,FIND("$",A1),FIND(" ",A1,FIND("$",A1))-FIND("$",A1))),RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-FIND("$",A1)+1))
```

Comment: I'm getting a `#VALUE!` error with this when I tried it on my first example...

Comment: Right, because there's no " " to find when it doesn't have the `(estimate)` right?

Comment: you are correct

Comment: @bobSmith1432 you can run an `iferror()` to fix it, see the answer adjusted.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, would this function work in Google Docs too?

Comment: All these functions seems to be implemented in google spreadsheets, not sure about syntax though